# Audacious player doesn't play a list of audio files, when I mark and open several files in the file manager, since the update from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: sound, updates, nautilus, audacious

Well it's pretty much in the title.

I did the Update to Ubuntu 18.04 with the update manager. However, now when I select several files in the file manager and hit enter, only the last in the list gets opened and played by Audacious.

---

Apparently, my system behaves a bit weird. Three options to open multiple sound files

- Selecting them in the file manager, hit enter
- Selecting them, right click and click on Open with Audacious
- Selecting them, right click, go to sub-menu Open with ..., and then selecting Audacious

Only when I do it following the steps listed in the last point, then Audacious opens all files and puts them in a list.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on 18.04 upgraded from 17.10. Check whether the Exec line in /usr/share/applications/audacious.desktop reads like "Exec=audacious %U" (must be capital U)

Comment: I narrowed it a bit down to hitting enter, or clicking **open with Audacious** in the context menu. However, when I go into the **open with ...** sub-menu on the context menu, and then select Audacious, it opens all files.

Comment: I could reproduce my observation with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and Audacious 3.9.

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug in nautilus, see Audacious issues [758](https://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/758) and [597](https://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/597) as well as Gnome Nautilus issue [117](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/117)

Comment: Do not hesitate to post your comment as an answer and accept it, even when you also asked it. this is perfectly fine on the site.

Comment: @DohnJoe I have the same problem! Can you write here as an answer how you solved it? That would be nice! Thanks!

Comment: There's apparently no solution, at least none that I know of. The maintainer of Audacious states, that this behaviour is caused by Nautilus. Unless this gets fixed in Nautilus, the problem will persist.

Comment: @DohnJoe Ok, that's nonsense, there is always a solution. ;) I'll post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the problem is with the developers of Audacious. They may say that this is not their problem, and rather a Nautilus problem, but they are the developers. So adapt! ;)

For those who do not want to wait, here is a working solution for Ubuntu 19.04. Create a script `/home/myuser/.config/audacious/start-audacious.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" >> ~/.config/audacious/playlist.m3u

# Check if another instance of this script is running.
pidof -o %PPID -x $0 >/dev/null && echo "ERROR: Script $0 already running" && exit 1

sleep 0.1
audacious ~/.config/audacious/playlist.m3u
rm ~/.config/audacious/playlist.m3u
```

Then allow execution of this file:

```
chmod +x /home/myuser/.config/audacious/start-audacious.sh
```

Then edit the file `/usr/share/applications/audacious.desktop` and replace `Exec=audacious %U` with `Exec=/home/myuser/.config/audacious/start-audacious.sh`.

That's it. No restart needed for any service. Now go take Nautilus to your `*.mp3` files, mark a couple, and press Enter. Audacious should open your selection.

P.S.: Replace `myuser` by your user! ;)

Comment: I will test this solution on my 18.04 LTS, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work.  Thanks

Comment: Depending on the speed of your machine you can adjust the delay after the process check. If you have a slow machine, you might want to set it to `sleep 0.5`.

Comment: @DohnJoe Have you tested?

Comment: I am testing this solution, and it is generally working. One minor thing however is still different from the behaviour which I am used to: I select a couple of sound files and hit enter; now the player opens and plays a playlist containing the selected files; so far so good. If I leave the player open, select different files and hit enter, then nothing happens, and the player continues with the initial playlist. I guess this is due to the check, am I right?

Comment: this didn't work for me on 20.04 focal fossa...

Answer (score 1):

This Nautilus bug will hopefully be gone in Nautilus version 40 - the [respective bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/117) has been closed by [this commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/commit/080f83385ff79a8be54ee31e7a45422138226f1f).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Audacious, then goto File --> Settings
2. Click "Playlist" tab
3. Unchecked "Clear the playlist when openning files"